# php artisan serve throws errors when zlib activated

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, zlib, laravel-artisan

I noticed a strange behaviour in my local development machine.

I'm developing a Laravel/VueJS based application.

My system:

`Ubuntu 18.04.3`

`Laravel 5.5.44`

`PHP 7.3.12`

After having launched the dev server with the usual `php artisan serve`, it's impossible to connect to the app on `localhost:8000`.

The app is only partially loaded. The html seems to load but the assets (css, js) are not. I get loads of `net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` on Chrome console but no errors at all in the artisan console.

On the other hand, the problem is solved when I launch the server with `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`.

I discovered that the problem seems related to the `zlib` php library. When it's activated, artisan trhows errors, otherwise everything works flawlessly.

I can work it out, but I'd like to understand why I get this strange behaviour.

**EDIT**

I attach the messages from Google Chrome console.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     FD_logo_white_text.png:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     FD_logo.png:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     app.js:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     app.css:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined    (index):1 
    at (index):1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     white-arrow.png:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     7.jpg:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     4.jpg:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE     manifest.json:1
```

Moreover, [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZCL.jpg) of the Network tab on Google Console.

Comment: What errors does artisan throw?

Comment: Hi @apokryfos, as I wrote, "I get loads of net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE on Chrome console but no errors at all in the artisan console."

Comment: It might be useful to provide an example response from the chrome network tab

Comment: @apokryfos you're right, I edited my question and added more info.

Comment: If you click on one of the failed (red) requests you should get information regarding the request and response headers. Try to check if there's anything unusual

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to explain. I already tried to do that and I'm a bit puzzled by what I got. When using [artisan](https://imgur.com/Bns7A3J) for instance, I simply do not get any response. The Response tab simply says "Failed to load response". On the other hand, when using the php built in server everything works ([here is same file for comparison](https://imgur.com/96Dx7L9))